# LaTex/TikZ - Box alignment

Tags: alignment, latex, draw, tikz

I created following LaTeX/TikZ script to draw a figure:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, fill=yellow!96!black, rectangle, 
      align=center, inner sep=3ex, font=\sffamily, label=below: Label1] (Box1) {
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
          inner sep=1ex, rounded corners=0pt,
          fill=white, font=\vphantom{Q}\sffamily] (Innerbox) {One \nodepart{two} Two};
    \end{tikzpicture}};
    \node[draw, inner sep=1ex, right=of Box1, label=below: Label2] (Box2) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}

{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, fill=yellow!96!black, rectangle, 
      align=center, inner sep=3ex, font=\sffamily, label=below: Label3] (Box3) {Four};
\end{tikzpicture}}};

    \draw (Box1) -- (Box2) -- (Box3);
    \draw[dashed] (Innerbox.one east) -- (Box2);
    \draw[dashed] (Innerbox.two east) -- (Box2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output image]

I want to solve following problems:

1. How can the boxes be aligned equal, so than the label below is always on the same level?
2. How can box "Four" be added (not within, but as a box like Box1) to the right of Box2, ideally with a dashed line from Box2 to Box3?

   Desired structure:

   [Box1] -- [Box2] -- [Box3]

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark the answer below as accepted, if it solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

My elementary approach to this picture:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% left box
\filldraw [fill=yellow, draw=black, ultra thick] (0,0) rectangle (8,-10);
\filldraw [fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick] (2,-2) rectangle (6,-5);
\filldraw [fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick] (2,-5) rectangle (6,-8);
\node at (4,-3.5) [font=\sffamily] {\Huge One};
\node at (4,-6.5) [font=\sffamily] {\Huge Two};
% right box
\filldraw [fill=white, draw=black, ultra thick] (12,0) rectangle (20,-10);
\filldraw [fill=yellow, draw=black, ultra thick] (13,-1) rectangle (19,-6);
\node at (16,-3.5) [font=\sffamily] {\Huge Four};
% labels
\node at (4,-11) {\Huge 1};
\node at (16,-11) {\Huge 2};
\node at (16,-7) {\Huge 3};
% lines
\draw [ultra thick] (8,-5) -- (12,-5);
\draw [loosely dashed, ultra thick] (6,-3.5) -- (12,-4);
\draw [loosely dashed, ultra thick] (6,-6.5) -- (12,-6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Here you can play with coordinates to align boxes as you like.

This tries to answer to part 1 of your question while part 2 of it is not well clear to me. Anyway if you like this code, you can develop it and edit box `Four` just by using `\filldraw`, `\draw` and `\node` as above.